# AG Grid table format date value in the filter "agDateColumnFilter" doesnt't work

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I'm using AG Grid table v31 for `agDateColumnFilter` I'm trying to change default date format from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd.mm.yyyy`.

If I use the exact `valueFormatter` just for column it works but in the filter doesn't work.

[image]

```js
{
      field: 'createdDate',
      headerName: 'Created',
      filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
      filterParams: dateFilterButtonsConfig,
    },

export const dateFilterButtonsConfig = {
  buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
  maxNumConditions: 1,
  valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) => formatDate(params),
};

function formatDate(dateString: string) {
  const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('/');

  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
}
```